# Find Eigen values of given matrix with nonfactorable polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, factoring

I'm having trouble finding the Eigen values for this matrix:

$$ A =\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&-2 \\ 1&3&0 \\ -2&0&5 \end{pmatrix} $$

I did $A - \lambda I $ and ended up with this matrix:

$$ A - \lambda I =\begin{pmatrix} -\lambda&1&-2 \\ 1&3-\lambda&0 \\ -2&0&5-\lambda \end{pmatrix} $$

I then took the determinant and got $ -\lambda^3 + 8 \lambda^2 - 10\lambda - 17 $, but I don't know what I can do from here. The above polynomial is not factorable. How would I find the Eigen values?

Comment: If it's not factorable, then you have to solve it numerically...and that's really all you can do.

Comment: But there must be at least one Real root, since the polynomial is of odd degree.

Comment: @Jared I'm sorry, I'm drawing blanks. I don't know what you mean by solving it numerically. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @yayu Use some kind of [rooting finding](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=a7d8ae4569120b5bec12e7b6e9648b86) software.  It appears your equation has one real root and two complex roots.

Comment: @yayu: Have you tried using Wolfram : https://www.wolframalpha.com/? You know the Complex roots are conjugates of each other.

Comment: I was trying to solve it without Wolfram Alpha, but it seems I have no choice. From Wolfram, I got $\lambda = -0.93, 3.19, 5.74 $. Are you both saying these are the roots?

Comment: @Jared Are you sure it might not be correct? I've found the determinant about 4 times and it always gives me the same polynomial.

Comment: Thank you both for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jared mentioned. You have to solve it numerically. I used Mathematica to obtain the following numbers.
$$
\lambda_1 \approx -0.929142304121661 \\
\lambda_2 \approx 3.18552786994252 \\
\lambda_3  \approx 5.74361443417914\\
$$

Comment: Thank you, this confirms what I obtained for the roots.

Comment: You're welcome :)